# Optimizing some Python to parse a string field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column named `assignment_name` that is parsed but takes quite a long time, about 20 minutes for ~400k rows. I'd like some help in making this faster if possible. The input data in `assignment_name` is unfortunately all over the place, hence the parsing and cleaning into a date type. Basically, what I'm trying to do is extract the `due_date` from the beginning of the `assignment_name` field. Input should follow a format of `MM/DD/YYYY Text` but that date can include dots or hyphens instead of slashes, since `Pandas.to_datetime` fortunately can recognize those patterns. If there's no space between the date and the following text like in row 1 below, then the script won't recognize a date, which I am perfectly fine with doing (no need to add this functionality). If there's just a date of `MM/DD` like in row 3, then this script again won't find a date which is perfectly fine. Then there are many records in the data like the last row where assignment_name will just be a generic name without a date, since dates are not always required in the name.

Hope that isn't too confusing. Here's example input and expected output (due_date) in the second column:

| assignment_name | due_date |
| --- | --- |
| 10/8/20TET:Convection2 |  |
| 09/18/2020 Pre-Test | 2020-09-18 00:00:00 |
| 12/10 U2L3.3 |  |
| 09/25/20 U1L4.1 HW Read | 2020-09-25 00:00:00 |
| 4/15/21 U3L1 | 2021-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 12/21/20 | 2020-12-21 00:00:00 |
| 1-6-21 CW 3.3 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 |
| 9.23.20 Barbie | 2020-09-23 00:00:00 |
| Play Write Ex. 1 |  |

Here's the Python snippet that's doing the parsing:

```
for index, row in data_normalized.iterrows():
    try:
        if row['assignment_name'].find(' ') == -1:
            due_date = row['assignment_name']
        else:
            due_date = row['assignment_name'][:row['assignment_name'].find(' ')]
        data_normalized.at[index, 'due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(due_date)
    except Exception as err:
        data_normalized.at[index, 'due_date'] = None
        continue
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try regular expression:

```
df["due_date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["assignment_name"].str.extract(r"^(\d+[/\.-]\d+[/\.-]\d+)(?:\s|$)")[0]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           assignment_name   due_date
0   10/8/20TET:Convection2        NaT
1      09/18/2020 Pre-Test 2020-09-18
2             12/10 U2L3.3        NaT
3  09/25/20 U1L4.1 HW Read 2020-09-25
4             4/15/21 U3L1 2021-04-15
5                 12/21/20 2020-12-21
6            1-6-21 CW 3.3 2021-01-06
7           9.23.20 Barbie 2020-09-23
8         Play Write Ex. 1        NaT
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always at before the 1st `' '` character, then you can also use:

```
df["due_date"] = pd.to_datetime(data_normalized['assignment_name'].str.split(' ').str[0], errors='coerce')
```